# VB.Net linq add GroupBy via expression tree

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, expression-trees

I'm looking for the corect syntax to add a GroupBy to a Linq Table dynamicaly because the group parameter can be changed in the user interface.

Basically I have a Linq.EntitySet to which i want to add a GroupBy for the changeable parameters

Day,
Week,
Month,
Year

Instead of writeing 4 queries like

```
data.View.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Moment.Date).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key).Select(Function(x) New With {.Date = x.Key, .Count = x.Count()})

data.View.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Moment.Week).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key).Select(Function(x) New With {.Date = x.Key, .Count = x.Count()})

data.View.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Moment.Month).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key).Select(Function(x) New With {.Date = x.Key, .Count = x.Count()})

data.View.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Moment.Year).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key).Select(Function(x) New With {.Date = x.Key, .Count = x.Count()})
```

I like to add the group by dynamically via expression tree or is there a simpler way?

thanks for advice!

Comment: If it's just four, why not do a switch statement?

Comment: yeah I could do a switch statement but there has to be a better way! I have to do this for more then one EntitySet and it will become very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Supprisingly it seams to be simpler than i thought!

```
    Private Function bar(x As Date) As Object
        Select Case ddlStatRange.SelectedValue
            Case 1
                Return x.Month
            Case 2
                Return x.Month
            Case 3
                Return x.Year
            Case Else
                Return x.Date
        End Select
    End Function

    Dim foo = data.View.GroupBy(Function(x) bar(x.Moment)).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key).Select(Function(x) New With {.Date = x.Key, .Count = x.Count()})
```

In any case if someone has a better idea :D

Comment: So, a switch statement, essentially? =)

Comment: yes but I didn't know how to cast the different types from the function. I supposed the type-analyzer of linq would fail with datatype object. But it's working :D